# Create a function to convert the type of array elements and return array's address

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a `Vector3` struct, consisting of three member values of type double.

```
struct Vector3 {
   double x, y, z;
};
```

I need to pass reference to an instance of this struct to a function that accepts arrays of type float. I can't change the type it accepts.

```
void foo(const float *value);
```

I could create a temporary array to change the type and pass it to the function:

```
Vector3 MyVector = Vector3(1, 2, 3);
const float temp[] = {(float)MyVector.x, (float)MyVector.y, (float)MyVector.z);
foo(temp);
```

While this works, I need to do this operation very often, and I would like to avoid the visual mess it creates.

Is there a good way to define a function that would convert the type of the member variables and pass that to `foo`? This is what I tried:

```
struct Vector3 {
  ...
  float* getPointer() {
     static float temp[3] = {x, y, z};
     return temp;
  }
}

struct Vector3 {
  ...
  float* getPointer() {
     std::vector<float> temp = {x, y, z};
     return temp.data();
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not smell C.

Comment: honestly, if you're using a sane compiler (gcc, clang, icc, msvc) just static_assert the struct size == 3*sizeof(double) and reinterpret_cast. If the types are incompatibile (float and double) you need to make a copy and store it in a temporary variable in the scope where the function is called

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate of the suggested question.  That asks "can I solve this problem with reinterpret cast" (with answer "no"), this questions "what other ways that solve this problem are there?"

Comment: How are you all missing that OP has a struct of doubles and needs to pass a pointer to float? reinterpret_cast cannot work here, not just because of some theoretical UB that has no real implications in any modern implementation, but because a double isn't a float. OP needs proper type conversion in an elegant way, creating and holding a temporary array of 3 floats somewhere that lives for the duration of the method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A temporary array can be hidden in a `class`:

```
class As_float_ptr {
public:
    As_float_ptr(const Vector3& vec) 
        : data{(float)vec.x, (float)vec.y, (float)vec.z}
    { }

    operator const float*() { return data; }

private:
    const float data[3];
};

Vector3 vec;
foo(As_float_ptr{vec});
```

The temporary object `As_float_ptr` will be destroyed only after `foo()` returns, so passing a pointer to its data member `data[3]` into `foo()` is safe.

If you want to support several storage types, you can do this:

```
template<std::size_t size>
class As_float_ptr {
public:
    As_float_ptr(const Vector2& vec) : data{(float)vec.x, (float)vec.y} {
        static_assert(size == 2);
    }

    As_float_ptr(const Vector3& vec) : data{(float)vec.x, (float)vec.y, (float)vec.z} {
        static_assert(size == 3);
    }

    operator const float*() { return data; }

private:
    const float data[size];
};

As_float_ptr(const Vector2&) -> As_float_ptr<2>;
As_float_ptr(const Vector3&) -> As_float_ptr<3>;

Vector2 vec2;
foo(As_float_ptr{vec2});

Vector3 vec3;
foo(As_float_ptr{vec3});
```

This code uses C++17 deduction guides to deduce the `size` template parameter from the type of the constructor parameter. If C++17 is not available, a `make`-type function can be used instead:

```
As_float_ptr<2> make_float_ptr(const Vector2& vec) {
    return As_float_ptr<2>{vec};
}

As_float_ptr<3> make_float_ptr(const Vector3& vec) {
    return As_float_ptr<3>{vec};
}

foo(make_float_ptr(vec2));
foo(make_float_ptr(vec3));
```

Comment: Interesting answer. I wondered: When is that temporary array destroyed? It must be alive until after foo() has returned, right?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, that's correct. It will be destroyed after `foo()` returns.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful! However say I have a different struct, Vec2. Should I create a separate class for this, or would it work to incorporate it inside the same class like this?`As_float_ptr(const Vector3& vec) : data3{(float)vec.x, (float)vec.y, (float)vec.z}
    { } As_float_ptr(const Vector2& vec) : data2{(float)vec.x, (float)vec.y}
    { }     void GetPointer3 { return data3; };  void GetPointer2 { return data2; } 
private:
    const float data3[3]; const float data2[2];`

Comment: @LennyWhite, that'll be a waste of storage. I'll add a possible solution in a few minutes.

Comment: @Evg Do you know where I can find documentation for the implicit conversion of `As_float_ptr` to `float *` for the first argument in the call to `foo()`? I have looked at the [Implicit conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) page, but could not find it..

Comment: @HåkonHægland, do you mean [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)?

Comment: Very nice!  I was going to edit my answer to include something like this, but I'm not us with C++17 deduction guides which make this very slick.

Answer (score 4):

Your first `getPointer` member function (with a static array) is legal, but very, very dangerous - it is not thread safe.

Your second attempt (create a temporary vector and return the .data()) is UB as soon as you attempt to refer to the function result (the temporary will be destroyed, and the pointer returned by .data() will no longer be valid)).

The other obvious solution is to provide an overload of `foo`.

```
void foo(const Vector3& value) {
    const float temp[] = {(float)value.x, (float)value.y, (float)value.z);
    foo(temp);
}
```

But that only works if there are only a few functions like `foo`.  It gets really nasty if there are multiple functions and multiple types like `Vector3`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Unfortunately there are indeed multiple functions and I do have multiple types like Vector3.

Comment: @Evg: Yes the overload creates a temporary array on the stack, and calls the real foo function.  Each thread calling foo will have its own copy of temp.

Comment: And how is that different from what OP had in his code where `temp` is declared just before `foo()` call? It will also be on stack.

Comment: @Evg The difference is that the initialization of `temp` only has to be written once (inside the definition of the overload function), not before every call to `foo` (which makes the code very messy, and it's easy to mistype it once as `{(float)value.x, (float)value.y, (float)value.y)`

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, I understand this. What I don't get is why that solution is not thread safe and how an overloaded `foo()` can solve thread safety problem.

Comment: Ah. We have been discussing different bits of code. I meant `float* getPointer() {
     static float temp[3] = {x, y, z};
     return temp;
  }` is not thread safe.  It's that `static float temp[3]` that blows the thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be create a struct with 3 floats that converts to `float const*`

```
struct Float3{
   operator float const*(){ return values; }
   float values[3];
};
```

and to return that by value from a converting function.

```
Float3 to_float3( Vector3 const& d ){
    return { { (float)d.x, (float)d.y, (float)d.z} };
}
```

This function can then be used like this:

```
Vector3 vec{};
foo( to_float3( vec ) );
```

See working version [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0247fa9f7bd687e0).

Comment: The problem is that `Float3*` cannot be converted to `float*` (You can `reinterpret_cast` it - but using the resulting pointer is undefined behaviour - as explained in the answers to the linked question.)

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica I've removed the address taking and added a user defined conversion which compiles and should be without UB.

Comment: Nope.  Accessing (&x)[0] is fine.  (&x)[1] is UB.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica but with the array then it is.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Martin's answer (new answer for better formatting): Write a templated version for this function:

```cpp
template<typename Func>
void wrapper(Func f, const Vector3d &value){
    const float temp[] = {(float)MyVector.x, (float)MyVector.y, (float)MyVector.z);
    f(temp);
}
```

For multiple types you can also do some templating if they are similar, but that depends on which types you have.

Disclaimer above is untested, I am on mobile right now.

Comment: This works well for all functions where we want to convert the first argument (we can make the wrapper varargs to pass through trailing arguments).  It doesn't work so well if the various functions take the argument as second, third, fourth, etc.